# Play sends HTML to client, but client browser doesn't render it

Tags: playframework

I have a simple play app. All of it's actions render to views. About 10% of the time, (can't determine a repro case), the page loads as if it's viewing source. All the HTML shows up in the client browser, but just as text, it doesn't get rendered as a webpage.

What would cause Play to just dump all the response text to the browser in a manner that prevents the browser from recognizing it as HTML and rendering it?

This has got me stumped, and it's a real pain for customers. Just hitting reload on their browser fixes it, but still, they don't know to do that.

Thanks in advance
Josh

Comment: but nowhere in my code am I setting headers, I just call render, and then randomly, (i never know when), sometimes the final HTML all gets dumped into the browser but the browser doesn't recognize it as HTML.

Comment: Never had this issue. Are you deploying in the standard Play way, or using another structure? Behind some proxy? Any modules used? What browser is the customer using? HAs that browser any addon?

Comment: @PereVillega Using Apache as a front end server as the play docs suggested. I am using web requests a lot in Play as my app calls out to other services while processing requests. It's all very SOA. I'm using the following code to make remote requests, could this be interfering with my main response back to the client?  `WSRequest req = WS.url(anotherURL);  
    req.setHeader("user_id", Long.toString(_userId));  
    req.setHeader("user_email", email);  
    req.body = "{some_json}";  
    req.mimeType = "application/json";  
    HttpResponse res = req.post(); Then I call render();`

Comment: @Joshua Gunder sorry about the delay answering. I'm afraid I'm not sure what may be the cause. I would check browsers and Apache, never had this issue with Play itself, so unless you modified some special configuration or you are using a very specific module, I wouldn't focus on it.

Comment: This is still happening, but I have more information now. The page that's coming to the browser as source and not getting rendered is the "route not found, but I tried all these other routes page". Hitting reload resolves the issue and on the second request Play finds the route just fine. So now I have two questions, 1) Why for a valid route, is Play not finding the route. 2) When it spits out the route not found page, why is the client not rendering the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some sleuthing, and it turns out the page whose html is getting returned is actually the 404 error page. I looked at the 404 page and realized it's content type is being set dynamically, (which is not the case with all my other screens). So I changed it from ${_response_encoding} to just be hardcoded to UTF-8 like all my other html templates. Soooo, I'm praying that explains why when the 404 page was sent to clients their browser didn't know what content type it was.